# Why won't this code run remotely on x64 based Windows machines

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-debugging

I have a piece of C# code which I am using to remotely register a *.tlb file in C#. I am deploying it using PsExec (Powershell) with the following command:

```
.\PsExec.exe \\* -u "username" -p "password" -h -c "MyExe.exe"
```

It works fine on x86 machines, but falls over on x64 machines with the following error: `-2146232576`.

If I run the *.exe locally on the 64 bit machine, it works fine. The code is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Directory");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            File.Copy(@"\\x.x.x.x\MyDll.dll", @"C:\Directory\MyDll.dll");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                var p = new Process
                            {
                                StartInfo =
                                    {
                                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe",
                                        Arguments = @"C:\Directory\MyDll.dll",
                                        UseShellExecute = false
                                    }
                            };


                var q = new Process
                            {
                                StartInfo =
                                    {
                                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe",
                                        Arguments = @"C:\Directory\MyDll.dll /tlb",
                                        UseShellExecute = false
                                    }
                            };


                var r = new Process
                            {
                                StartInfo =
                                    {
                                        FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe",
                                        Arguments = @"C:\Directory\MyDll.dll /codebase",
                                        UseShellExecute = false
                                    }
                            };

                p.Start();
                q.Start();
                r.Start();
            }
            catch(Exception z)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(z.Message);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done and Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is 1792 = ERROR_NETLOGON_NOT_STARTED = "An attempt was made to logon, but the network logon service was not started."

This [article](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec) by Mark Russinovich talks about the security aspects of PsExec.

try running this with -i option.